# Forced to restart COM+ as AD "login" stops; EnsureAppDomainConfigured error

Tags: 2009

Unable to Initialize TDSE object.
Invalid procedure call or argument

Error Code:
0x5 (5)

Call stack:
TemplateTypeUtilities.EnsureAppDomainConfigured
TDSE.Initialize

That is the error message we see in Tridion ContentManager Event view. The users cannot log in to the CMS server and the only way is (if we don't want to reboot server) is to restart the Tridion Content Manager COM+ component service. We know that somehow the CMS loses all info on the Domain to authenticate users against but there are no other issues we have found. Just this single problem. User can still use LDAP authentication but majority of our users are coming over via AD.

We have not found anything and there is nothing on Google about the call stack error. Anyone recognize this? Tridion2009SP1

Comment: Are you sure that this is not due to the COM+ using too much memory and causing issues? That is a known issue that is extremely similar to this.